# How can I draw this phase diagram in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, polyhedra

Currently, Master's student in Mathematical physics and I am doing research about QUANTUM CRyptography.

Please can someone show me how to draw the phase diagrams for this function here? [image]

How can I draw a plot like this one?
[image]

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to write the function in this site !

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @NabilKhossossi Can you share a link to the source of the graph?

Comment: http://sci-hub.cc/10.1142/S0217979209053631 page 6 !

Comment: You would use `ContourPlot`.

Comment: thank u @Jens i have another question, I want to plot another function but this time with three variables w1, w2 and w3 for different values of w3 = 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1

a plot like this one on page 8 (fig 4 ) in link : http://sci-hub.cc/10.1142/S0217979209053631

Comment: You could create one plot as above for each parameter value and then combine the plots using `Show`. To get a real answer, you'll have to provide copyable code in the question, and make sure to define all the functions needed to make the plots.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write the  
entier code, I don't know if it is possible to send u the file.nb on this site